# Gradle create different distributions

Tags: java, gradle

i am new to gradle and i am trying to create several applications/distributions of a java application, to be used in different operating systems.

I need one application/distro for each: Windows64,Windows32,Linux64,Linux32.
The difference between these are that there are different dependencies (jar files from external projects) for each distro, and also some dll files must be included in some distros.

Finally, windows distros do not need unix build scripts and vice versa.

I've tried reading the gradle user guide and searching for answers online, but i do not have any experience in this and i don't know what to look for. Any help?

Comment: I think you might be looking for something [like this](https://blog.gradle.org/maven-pom-profiles)

Answer (score 1):

You could likely use my [java-flavours](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours) plugin

Eg:

```
ext {
    someApiVersion = '1.0'
}
plugins {
    id "com.lazan.javaflavours" version "1.2"
}
javaFlavours {
    flavour 'windows32'
    flavour 'windows64'
    flavour 'linux32'
    flavour 'linux64'
}
dependencies {
    compile           "log4j:log4j:1.2.17"
    compile           "foo:xxx-interfaces:$someApiVersion"
    compileWindows32  "foo:xxx-windows32:$someApiVersion"
    compileWindows64  "foo:xxx-windows64:$someApiVersion"
    // etc
}
```

Each `flavour` will produce a separate jar by joining common sources (`src/main/java` and `src/main/resources`) with flavour specific sources (`src/$flavour/java` and `src/$flavour/resources`). There's also support for flavour specific tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different build script (`windows64.gradle`, `windows32.gradle`, `linux64.gradle`, `linux32.gradle` etc...) and load them thanks to a specific project property

```
def defaultPlatform = 'windows64'
ext.platform = project.hasProperty('pf') ? pf : defaultPlatform

apply from: "${ext.platform}.gradle"
```

And then just run `gradle -Ppf=linux64 build` or `gradle -Ppf=linux64 yourCustomTask`

In each `.gradle` file, add specific dependencies etc...